# Getting text from inside an HTML tag within a local file with grep

Tags: html, regex, bash, screen-scraping, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Excerpt From Input File

```
<TD class="clsTDLabelWeb" width="28%">Municipality:&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 394px" class="clsTDLabelSm" colSpan="5">
<span id="DInfo1_Municipality">JUPITER</span></TD>
```

My Regular Expression

```
(?<=<span id="DInfo1_Municipality">)([^</span>]*)
```

I have an HTML file saved to disk. **I would like to use grep to search through the file and output the contents of a specific span**, though I don't know if this is a proper use of grep. When I run grep on the file with the expression read from another file (so I dont mess up escaping any special characters), it doesn't output anything. I have tested the expression in RegExr and it matches "JUPITER" which is exactly what I want returned. Thank you so much for your help!

Desired Output

```
JUPITER
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
sed -n 's|^<span id="DInfo1_Municipality">\([^<]*\)</span></TD>$|\1|p' file
```

or with GNU `grep` and your regex:

```
grep -Po '(?<=<span id="DInfo1_Municipality">)([^</span>]*)'
```

Comment: Passing the -P flag to grep allowed me to do the lookbehind/lookahead I was after. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Grep doesn't support that type of regex (lookbehind assertions), and its a very poor tool for this, but for the example given it is workable, will break under many situtions.

```
grep -io "<span id=\"DInfo1_Municipality\">.*</span>" file.htlm | grep -io ">[^<]*" | grep -io [^>]*
```

something crazy like that, not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling I was trying to do something that grep didn't support. It looks like I'll have to do some actual programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/DInfo1_Municipality/s/<\/span.*//p' file | sed 's/.*>//'
```